# Why assembly language doesn't need to be compiled?

Tags: assembly, binary, computer-science

I read that assembly language doesn't need to be directly compiled to binary and that it can run as it is.

if that's true, how is that possible? how does the machine understands words and numbers directly?

Comment: It needs to be assembled, which is different from "compiling"

Answer (score 4):

It's not true. Assembly code needs to be assembled into machine code before it can be run directly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this article witch details the compilation process of C code. It will clear up some things: https://medium.com/@minas_anton/stages-of-compilation-process-8ac4ead4a21.

Assembly code still needs to be processed to get machine code, just that process is usually not refereed to as compilation.